# First example in struts 2 tutorial

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

I want to start using Struts 2 framework, I download [Struts 2.2.3](http://struts.apache.org/downloads.html)
 , and follow this [tutorial](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/create-struts-2-web-application-with-artifacts-in-web-inf-lib-and-use-ant-to-build-the-application.html)  to make first example, but when I run the index.jsp which has

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s"  uri="/struts-tags" %>
 ....
<p><a href="<s:url action='hello'/>">Hello World</a></p>
..
```

This exception occurs:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The Struts dispatcher cannot be found.  This is usually       caused by using Struts tags without the associated filter. Struts tags are only usable when the  request has passed through its servlet filter, which initializes the Struts dispatcher needed for this tag. - [unknown location]
```

I didn't specify any filters in web.xml because web.xml file wass not created when I create the web application ?! There's only sun-web.xml file that exists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the tutorial which you linked yourself.

> ### Step 5 - Add Struts 2 Servlet Filter
>
> To enable the Struts 2 framework to work with your web application you **need** to add a Servlet filter class and filter mapping to web.xml. Below is the filter and filter-mapping nodes you should add to web.xml.
>
> #### web.xml Servlet Filter
>
> ```xml
> <filter>
>   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
>   <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
> </filter>
>
> <filter-mapping>
>   <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
>   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
> </filter-mapping>
> ```
>
> For more information about configuring the deployment descriptor for Struts 2 see [web.xml](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/webxml.html). Note the url-pattern node value is /* meaning the Struts 2 filter will be applied to all URLs for this web application.

Did you read it? Create the web.xml (the IDE should usually already have done it) and declare the filter in there as per the instructions in the tutorial.

Comment: yes I did, the problem I mention that web.xml file has not created when I build the project, I make a copy of web.xml file from another project and add it to this project, and add the filter but another exception occur , which is 
"Unable to load configuration. - bean - jar:file:/D:/f/alaa%20college/year%204/2ed%20semester/Advance%20SW%20application/struts/FirstStrutsTest/build/web/WEB-INF/lib/struts2-gxp-plugin-2.2.3.jar!/struts-plugin.xml:8:162 "

Comment: That's a different problem. Ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with Struts2 take a look at the [Maven Archtypes](https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/struts-2-maven-archetypes.html). 
How it works is described here.

[4 Easy Steps to create a Java based Web Application with Struts2 and jQuery](http://www.jgeppert.com/2011/05/4-easy-steps-to-create-a-java-based-web-application-with-struts2-and-jquery/)